# css overflow hidden issue

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with overflow hidden of an element.

I want the green border box to be overlapped a little bit by the red box as shown in the second example.

```
<ul>
    <li id="first_slide">sdsdsadsadasdas</li>
    <li>sdsdsadsadasdas</li>
</ul>
<section class="footer">some content </section>
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/XyNTZ/1/

Is it possible to lift the footer box a little bit up but without using any position.

Comment: What do you mean without using any position? Position needs to be modified in order to stack the elements.

Comment: Well I know what position is meant for. I asked if it is possible or not to achieve the desired output in some other way but not using position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `margin-top:-10px;`. But without positioning you might have problems with overlapping.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know it will be a problem without using position.But the footer is meant to be at the very bottom of the page.If I do margin-top then there will be a white gap/space at the bottom.

Comment: If you dont care about footer content that will not be shown, then maybe make footer smaller and make content appear with negative margin-top?

Comment: All good man. Thanks once again.This is something called presence of mind instead giving theoretical knowledge(^)

Comment: Haha, thanks :D It's like LOGOs - you have to understand the principle ;)